# Efficient algorithm for filtering

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I m working on a application which is a service. I am receiving a request object and I need to pass this object through set of filters and return the response. There are about 10 filters I need to pass the object through.

Currently the application is doing a sequential search on every filter as follows:

```
public List<Element) FilterA(Request request){
  for(Element element in items)
  {
     // compare element to request object elements   
     // there are different field checking per object
  }
}
```

So there is FilterB, FilterC etc. they are all done in similar fashion, within for loops different fields are being compared.

Can this be done via hashset? or Binary search?

Or is there an efficient algorithm. Essentially I d like to improve the O(n) to something less.

Comment: Can you thread the filters? That will at least get all 10 running at the same time which should help.

Comment: @twain249 yes I can do that, but what if there is a sequence in the filters? like sequential filtering?

Comment: I don't know your unique requirements. If you can't thread the filters you can't. As for the data structures is there any way to sort them (so you can do a binary search)? Also you could try to build a `Map` if you have a key you can use.

Comment: If you know from the context, that most elements will pass filter a, b, c, but fail to pass x, y, z, you should start filtering for x, y, z, because then you have less and less elements to test against your filters. That's why I don't really understand the idea of parallel filtering. Would that mean independently, and in the end building the intersection?

Comment: Unless there is an ordering in the data you cannot improve your results since you have to look at each element atleast once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have *n* lists and *f* filters there are bascially only two approaches: iterate through the list and apply each filter to each individual element (keep it if it passes all of them, remove it otherwise); or do what you're doing now and let each filter iterate over the entire list. Both have a worst-case complexity of O(n*f), assuming O(1) element removal (I recommend using a LinkedList to achieve this, copy the contents to one if necessary).

You can really only improve upon this complexity by utilising properties of your input. Maybe you can combine multiple filters into one (when they're range checks, for instance) or maybe taking one element from the list will also result in the removal of others. Also, if you can guess which filters will probably remove more elements it will pay off to run these first.

So yeah, it really depends on what kind of stuff you're filtering and what your filters look like. In the most general case you can't win much (as long as you're already using lists from which you can remove elements in O(1) time) but you might gain something if you take knowledge of your input into account.